# callback error on ajaxfileupload

Tags: jquery, asp.net

hi guys i am having a problem with the ajaxfileupload plugin my image is being uploaded but the callback returns error

here is the error that the developer tool is showing

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'handleError' ajaxfileupload.js:107
uploadCallback
```

the error points on this line of code from the plugin

```
jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);
```

looking for some answer i've been looking all over google
thanks

Comment: what version of jquery r u using mate..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check if the `script` file is being included properly loaded.If If console shows an error like '`no method`'it's may be probably because it's not being `referenced or called properly` on your site.

Secondly check the `version` of jQuery you are using,coz the latest version of jquery does not use `handleError()` method.I think this might work on `jquery versions` less than `< 1.6`.If you are looking for a gud `file upload plugin` you might try the [jquery.form.js](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)

Comment: yup i think the error is with code itself being that the handleerror is not supported the script is loaded 200ok response

Comment: so if u are adament on using this plugin,try with lower versions of js